# How to get checked status of SwitchCompat using Databinding in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

When I click on Register Button I need to get **checked status** of SwitchCompat using databinding.

Below is code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
   android:id="@+id/switchSymbols"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:isChecked="@={myCustomModel.upperCase}"
   android:text="" />
```

In MyCustomModel class

```
 var upperCase: Boolean
    @Bindable get() = _isUpperCase
    set(value){
        _isUpperCase = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.upperCase)
    }
```

Now I want to get status using below code

```
var isUpperCase = myCustomModel.upperCase
```

I am getting the following error

```
Cannot find a getter for <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat android:isChecked> that accepts parameter type 'boolean'

If a binding adapter provides the getter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this? How can I get checked the status of SwitchCompat?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be checked not isChecked?

```
android:checked="@={@={myCustomModel.upperCase}}"
```

Comment: Yes, It was my mistake. I realised and fixed